# How to replace an entire cell with NaN on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the entire cell that contains the word as circled in the picture with blanks or NaN. However when I try to replace for example '1.25 Dividend' it turned out as '1.25 NaN'. I want to return the whole cell as 'NaN'. Any idea how to work on this?

[image: My DataFrame]

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**
Use a regular expression in your replace

```
df.replace('^.*Dividend.*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

*From comments*

(Using `regex=True`) means that it will interpret the problem as a regular expression one.  You still need an appropriate pattern.  The `'^'` says to start at the beginning of the string.  `'^.*'` matches all characters from the beginning of the string.  `'$'` says to end the match with the end of the string.  `'.*$'` matches all characters up to the end of the string.  Finally, `'^.*Dividend.*$'` matches all characters from the beginning, has `'Dividend'` somewhere in the middle, then any characters after it.  Then replace this whole thing with `np.nan`

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2 Dividend'], [3, 4], [5, '6 Dividend']])
df

   0           1
0  1  2 Dividend
1  3           4
2  5  6 Dividend
```

then the proposed solution yields

```
   0    1
0  1  NaN
1  3  4.0
2  5  NaN
```

---

**Option 2**
Another alternative is to use `pd.DataFrame.mask` in conjunction with a `applymap`.
If I pass a `lambda` to `applymap` that identifies if any cell has `'Dividend'` in it.

```
df.mask(df.applymap(lambda s: 'Dividend' in s if isinstance(s, str) else False))

   0    1
0  1  NaN
1  3    4
2  5  NaN
```

---

**Option 3**
Similar in concept but using `stack`/`unstack` + `pd.Series.str.contains`

```
df.mask(df.stack().astype(str).str.contains('Dividend').unstack())

   0    1
0  1  NaN
1  3    4
2  5  NaN
```

Comment: ```pd.np.nan``` will also give the same result if you don't want to import ```numpy``` explicitly.

Comment: Hi, it works! At first I set regex as False. So that mean if we set regex as True it will replace the whole cell?

Comment: @HaAnTran no!  It means that it will interpret the problem as a regular expression one.  You still need an appropriate pattern.  The `'^'` says to start at the beginning of the string.  `'^.*'` matches all characters from the beginning of the string.  `'$'` says to end the match with the end of the string.  `'.*$'` matches all characters up to the end of the string.  Finally, `'^.*Dividend.*$'` matches all characters from the beginning, has `'Dividend'` somewhere in the middle, then any characters after it.  Then replace this whole thing with `np.nan`

Answer (score 0):

Replace all strings:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: What if the cells were strings and OP wanted to keep them strings?  OP asked to replace the dividend cells.  You can modify this to `df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).isnull())` but then suffers from the problem that it will also mask any other string like cells like `Cash` or `Shares` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I would use applymap like this

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 'NaN' if (type(x) is str and 'Dividend' in x) else x)
```